# C# string array.length error when calling from a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I'm fairly new to C# and im writing a rental vehicle management system. I'm trying to retrieve all lines from a CSV file that is set up like this:

```
[Registration][Grade][Make][Model][Year][NumSeats][Transmission][Fuel][GPS][SunRoof][DailyRate][Colour]
[123ABC][Economy][Toyota][Camry][2005][5][Automatic][Petrol][No][No][30][White]
[234BCD][Economy][Ford][Focus][2012][5][Automatic][Petrol][Yes][No][45][Blue]
[987ZYX][Economy][Holden][Cruise][2016][5][Manual][Diesel][Yes][No][60][Red]
```

and then iterate it through a for loop before it's sent to another method.

In the following method beyond the one shown, it's being put into an `ArrayList` so that the values retrieved can be searched for by the user in the program.

I'm stuck on the `for` loop as it gives me an error on the `vehicles1.Length;` saying that `vehicles1` is a use of an unassigned local variable. I don't know if initializing the array is my problem, because I've tried that and it gives me no errors but the program just breaks.

```
void setUpVehicles(out Fleet fleetVehicles)
{
    const char DELIM = ',';
    Vehicle veh = new Vehicle();
    FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FILENAME3, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);
    string recordIn;
    string[] vehicles1;
    recordIn = reader.ReadLine();

    while (recordIn != null)
    {
        string year = veh.Year.ToString();
        string seats = veh.NumSeats.ToString();
        string gps = veh.GPS.ToString();
        string sunRoof = veh.SunRoof.ToString();
        string dailyRate = veh.DailyRate.ToString();
        vehicles1 = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
        veh.Registration = vehicles1[0];
        veh.Grade = vehicles1[1];
        veh.Make = vehicles1[2];
        veh.Model = vehicles1[3];
        year = vehicles1[4];
        seats = vehicles1[5];
        veh.Transmission = vehicles1[6];
        veh.Fuel = vehicles1[7];
        gps = vehicles1[8];
        sunRoof = vehicles1[9];
        dailyRate = vehicles1[10];
        veh.Colour = vehicles1[11];  
    } 

    fleetVehicles = new Fleet();

    for (int i = 0; i < vehicles1.Length; i++)
    {
        fleetVehicles.insertVehicle(vehicles1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: csv data can be surprisingly complicated, and `String.Split()` will get you into trouble real quick. You want a real csv parser. Look on NuGet.

Comment: @Jawad ? While indeed variable need to be initialized your suggestion of value makes no sense... maybe you wanted to say "use `.Split` which would be more reasonable but bad suggestion (The code in the question is very strange anyway - it presumably tries to get data from string but does not even try to extract any values... just using some values that don't cause compilation errors... TDD Extremus)

Comment: That data you posted is not CSV so something you're not telling us is going on.

Comment: Also, ArrayList has been **obsolete for 15 years**, since generics were added to Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<Vehicle> setUpVehicles(string fileName)
{
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    using(var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.TextFieldParser(reader))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.Delimiters = new string[] {","};
        string[] row;

        while(!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            row = parser.ReadFields();
            var vehicle = new Vehicle {
               Registration = row[0],
               Grade = row[1],
               Make = row[2],
               Model = row[3],
               Year = row[4],
               NumSeats = row[5],
               Transmission = row[6],
               Fuel = row[7],
               GPS = row[8],
               SunRoo = row[9],
               DailyRate = row[10],
               Colour = row[11]
            };
            yield return vehicle;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would call it to make a fleet like this:

```
var fleetVehicles = new Fleet();
foreach(var vehicle in setUpVehicles(FILENAME3))
{
    feetVehicles.insertVehicles(vehicle);
}
```